# Can we use Synclient to set a trackpad gesture to a keystroke combo?

Tags: shortcut-keys, touchpad

Is there a way to use Synclient (for example) to set a double finger tap to "internet back" button, i.e. keystroke Alt+Left Arrow?

I found one four post saying yes, but see nothing in the Synclient help, just buttons 1, 2 or 3.

Thanks!

Comment: Take 2 steps. Configure the taps to get middle button. After that configure programs to use middle button to trigger something.  Answer on howto depends on the prigram you use or the  window manager. I asked similar about XFWM4, to change middle button to trigger something. ago. Answer was "you must edit the source code". In firefox, I have middle button set to open new tab. You need figure how to do similar.  One caution: make sure synclient works, can change some settings. On my system, I have libinput and synclient has no effect.

Comment: Thank you, but that is what I thought. Middle button is already being used. I thought there were systems with multiple touchpad buttons, like back, forward?